# Problem with wide voltage range CC sinking

Tags: transistors, constant-current, negative-voltage

I want to sink ~10 mA of constant current at wide range of voltages even lower voltages like 10 mV, below circuit suggested to me in one of my older questions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPcaFF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is when input voltage is zero, output will became negative ([link to simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20432%20224%20528%20224%200%0Aw%20432%20352%20432%20224%200%0As%20432%20352%20496%20352%200%200%20false%0Ag%20544%20368%20544%20416%200%0Ap%20816%20224%20816%20176%201%200%0Aw%20544%20336%20544%20272%200%0Af%20496%20352%20544%20352%2032%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20704%20224%20816%20224%200%0A370%20704%20224%20704%20272%201%200%0Ag%20656%20288%20656%20320%200%0AR%20704%20384%20704%20416%200%200%2040%20-5%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20704%20304%20704%20384%200%20430%0At%20656%20288%20704%20288%200%201%200.633960678721419%200.6644650508887109%20100%0Aw%20560%20224%20704%20224%200%0AR%20432%20224%20384%20224%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20464%20272%20464%20288%200%0Ai%20464%20272%20544%20272%200%200.001%0At%20544%20272%20544%20224%201%201%20-9.994437786945026%200.6395228917763932%20100%0A)):

[image]

Making another path for the current to flow solves the problem to some degree but the output is still negative ([link to simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20432%2096%20528%2096%200%0Aw%20432%20224%20432%2096%200%0As%20432%20224%20496%20224%200%200%20false%0Ag%20544%20240%20544%20288%200%0Ap%20816%2096%20816%2048%201%200%0Aw%20544%20208%20544%20144%200%0Af%20496%20224%20544%20224%2032%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20704%2096%20816%2096%200%0A370%20704%2096%20704%20144%201%200%0Ag%20656%20160%20656%20192%200%0AR%20704%20256%20704%20288%200%200%2040%20-5%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20704%20176%20704%20256%200%20430%0At%20656%20160%20704%20160%200%201%200.002154906553417354%200.6551311255346697%20100%0Aw%20560%2096%20704%2096%200%0AR%20432%2096%20384%2096%200%200%2040%2010%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20464%20144%20464%20160%200%0Ai%20464%20144%20544%20144%200%200.001%0At%20544%20144%20544%2096%201%201%20-9.994115718733903%200.008039187819514144%20100%0Ag%20544%20368%20544%20400%200%0Aw%20544%20336%20816%20336%200%0Aw%20816%20336%20816%2096%200%0At%20496%20352%20544%20352%200%201%200.653142026504108%200.6509871199506907%20100%0Ar%20496%20224%20496%20352%200%201000%0A)):

[image]

- How can I prevent the output from getting negative?

Comment: The circuits don't really explain what you are trying to achieve - after all, why would they given that you are dissatisfied with them. So there is no real clue as to what you are wanting to do and your circuit offerings don't work. Where would that leave anyone reading your question?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm sorry I don't understand which part of the question is not clear, I need to sink 10 mA of current to maintain a minimum load. the circuit is an example circuit, is part of a bigger circuit and it's working in an "example" form.

Comment: @Andyaka On the second thought; what did you mean by: "given that you are dissatisfied with them"?

Comment: Are you perfectly satisfied with the circuit performance you get? I read that you are not. Also I don't read what you are properly trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know how else with my poor English language knowledge I can explain it, I want to sink 10 mA of current in order to be able to regulate the voltage of a PSU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhzH0p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A quick test.*

I suspect that your problem is that Q1's emitter is one diode-drop below ground - maybe at -0.6 or -0.7 V. Meanwhile the transistor is in saturation so the collector is probably 0.2 V higher than the emitter at -0.5 V.

A quick test would be to raise the base voltage by one diode drop - done here by R2 and Q2. This should hold the emitter closer to 0 V and may be adequate for your problem. I've chosen to use the base emitter junction as a diode so that the voltage drops will match.

Comment: It's really difficult to get the output to 0V, it needs some fine resistor adjusting, [link to simulator](http://tinyurl.com/y9jnrlpy).

Comment: Found the solution with your guidance, with your permission I'm adding it to your answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I rejected your edit. It doesn't work. There is no active component in your current sink so it won't hold the current constant. Add it to your question instead for further comment.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after submitting the edit. when raising the base voltage it can't keep the current constant at low input voltages. appreciate it if you offer another solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the one I gave you. What do you need it for anyway? It's not an LM317-based power-supply, is it?

Comment: No, I replaced that with a nice darlington configuration. earlier in the simulator it couldn't regulate the voltage without at least 1mA of load and now it's regulating without any load. weird! maybe it was a bug in the simulator...

Comment: A Darlington will give two b-e voltage drops. You ducked my other question.

Comment: Your solution raises the transistor base from ground, raising it makes it unable to pull the same amount of current at lower voltages.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The "laser" here is whatever your load is.  You set the program current with "Rset".  Because Rset is parallel to the BJT base-emitter junction, the circuit will self-adjust to ensure Vrest = Vbe = 0.7V

You just pick a resistor to give you your target current.    Say you want 10mA load, so Rset=Vrset/Irest = 0.7 / 0.010 = 70 ohms

Of course, it works with almost any small-signal NPN transistors, you don't need to use the ones shown in the example.

This is our 'go to circuit' for low-cost control of LED's.

Comment: But it can't keep the current constant when voltage drops to for example 10 mV.

Comment: I don't understand.  When what voltage drops to 10mV?  The input source voltage???

Comment: Yes, the input voltage.

Comment: That's not trivial to do with a few discrete transistors.   IMO you should address it with an opamp.    i.e.  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa046/sboa046.pdf?ts=1587925497728        Figures 12 & 13  are probably what you're looking for.     The opamp, of course, could not be powered by this same 10mV source voltage.

Comment: Really useful article, thanks.